# Should the Apple Meta be its own site on chat.SE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I've just noticed that for some reason the Apple.SE site's meta is considered a separate site for the purposes of chat:

[image]

Given it is the only local-meta that gets this treatment, is this correct, or something that should be fixed?

Comment: The word "different" _is_ right there in the site name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drop-down is influenced in part by what exists. Since there *is* an apple-meta room, it appears. In the general case, it would be more correct for that room to be aimed at apple.stackexchange.com; I am unclear  why that room invented itself - I will check, but it was 6 months ago, so it might have been a long-resolved bug.

Since this room is vacant, I'll delete it (in addition to changing it to apple.stackexchange.com, just in case ;p)